# `mv` has failed because of insufficient disk space, what now?

Tags: backup, rsync

I have tried to move a folder `A` from partition a to partition b as folder `B` with `mv`. Now the target file system was not big enough for all the data (I know I should have checked this first).

Anyway, I continued by using `rsync -av` (what I should have done in the first place), as in [What does mv do in case of errors?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43014/what-does-mv-do-in-case-of-errors/43017#43017)

Then I used `diff -r A B` to check for changes between the folders and diff indeed observed differences in the target directory. Now I wonder whether I should just delete the target folder and start the rsync process at once or whether there is a way to get `rsync` copy everything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's highly implementation dependent. Most `mv` I have seen leave the *half* file at the destination and let it be up to you to clean up the mess. I have never seen `mv` remove the source before the destination were completely copied, but not necessarily sync'ed to disk.
When moving multiple files it's most common that `mv` start copying and first remove source files when all files are copied, but again, I have seen `mv` handle one file at a time, think it were on an HP-UX machine many years ago.

I'd say, if it's important to you , you will have to either find some detailed documentation, check the source or do some experiments.